# Googel Apps Script hasNext() returns false

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying a very simple thing but can't seem to get it to work

I have a number of files with the same name "Facturas 21" living in different subfolders in my drive. I want to do stuff to them but I cannot access them with the file iterator for some reason.

My code is as simple as it gets:

```
function getFiles() {
  const drive = DriveApp.getFolderById("XXXXXXXXX");
  const files = drive.getFilesByName("Facturas 21");

  Logger.log(files.hasNext()); // logs false!

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    let file = files.next();
    ... some code
  }
}
```

Why is it giving me false when it's a fact that there are those files? FYI, I've copied and pasted the string, so no misspelling or mistyping.
According to the docs, `getFilesByName()` "gets a collection of all files in the user's Drive that have the given name" and returns a FileIterator object. What am I not seeing??

Comment: Question: if you just run `var files = DriveApp.getFiles();`, and `Logger.log(files.hasNext())`, does it return false? If so, it might be a token issue. In theory, getFiles() with no parameter should return an iterator with _all_ available files.

Comment: Thanks @AaronMorefield for your input. running `Driveapp.getFiles();` does give me a collection of all the files, and funny enough, if I try `Driveapp.getFilesByName("Facturas 21");` I also get `true` on `files.hasNext()`. My problem now is that the files I'm after live in a particular shared drive and there may be others on other shared drives over which I have no control so I should ideally stick to that particular shared drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to traverse the whole tree of content. Drive won't do that for you.

You're getting an empty FileIterator, presumably because you don't have any files named "Facturas 21" directly in folder XXX.

Recursively call `drive.getFolders()` until you reach the child node.

Comment: Thanks @mary for your input. I am going to accept this answer as the most convenient for me at this time but I have to recognise that ale13's answer is probably better practice.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this line `Logger.log(files.hasNext());` returns `false` is mainly because you are performing the search in the specific folder with the id you provisioned.

Just like mentioned in the other answer, you will have to traverse the whole Drive tree.

However, you may benefit from using the below snippet in order to list all the files named "Facturas 21":

```
function listFiles() {
  var query = "title contains 'Facturas 21'";
  let files = Drive.Files.list({q: query}).items;
  // code
}
```

The code above makes use of the `Drive` advanced service and is returning all the files named "Facturas 21" from the whole Drive. The `files` variable returned will be an array of objects of type `File`, so depending on the end result you are expecting, you can manipulate these for your needs.

#### Note

Please bear in mind that the `Drive` advanced service makes use of Drive API v2.

#### Reference

- [Drive API v2 Search Terms](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/ref-search-terms);
- [Drive API v2 Files:list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/list);
- [Apps Script Advanced Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive).

Comment: Thanks @ale13 for your input. It seems quite elegant and would probably be the most optimised way of getting a list of files, be that in an array of objects or in any other way. My only issue with your code is that I'm not yet familiar with the Drive advance service nor the querying syntax, and while I'm still a newbie, I think I'll take mary's answer as the most helpful to me in this occasion.
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation:**

According to this [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator#hasNext()), the `hasNext()` method of the **Class FileIterator** returns a `Boolean` value. Thus, this is the reason why you're getting "false" or "true" result when you run your code `Logger.log(files.hasNext());`.

Additionally, I tried your code and I was able to get the "Facturas 21" file as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cODMI.png) by adding the file's extension (in my case it's .txt) on the line 3 `const files = drive.getFilesByName("Facturas 21.txt");`. This is the main reason why you're only getting the false result.

Comment: Thanks for your input @irvin jay g., but I am indeed expecting to get a boolean value,  just not "false". 
Regarding the file extension, the files I'm looking for are all Google spreadsheets, so no extension there.